# Exponential factor in arrhenius equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

In Physical Chemistry by Peter Atkins and Julio de Paula, the exponential factor $e^{-E_{a}/RT}$ indicates the fractions of particles/molecules that have at least the energy $E_{a}$. I'm slightly confused because from what I've learnt in statistical thermodynamics the exponential factor should be proportional to the fraction of molecules in the energy level $E_{a}$ (i.e. doesnt include molecules with energy $> E_{a} $, to find the fraction of molecules with $\geq E_{a} $, i think one should sum/integrate from the energy level $ E_{a} $ to all higher accessible energy levels). Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term $e^{-\beta E_a}$ *is* in fact the integrated term. This derivation relies on assuming uniformly spaced energy levels $\epsilon$, such that the partition function is:

$$Z = \sum_{i=0} ^ \infty e^{-\beta i\epsilon}$$

Since $p_i = \frac{e^{-\beta i \epsilon}}{Z}$, you can sum up all $p_i$ from an $i_{min}$ to $\infty$, such that $i_{min}\epsilon\equiv E_a$:

$$p_{transition} = \sum_{i=i_{min}}^\infty p_i=\sum_{i=i_{min}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\beta i \epsilon}}{Z} = e^{-\beta i_{min} \epsilon} \frac{\sum_{i=0} ^ \infty e^{-\beta i\epsilon}}{Z} = e^{-\beta i_{min} \epsilon} \frac{Z}{Z} \equiv e^{-\beta E_a}$$

Edit: the third step is probably the trickiest one to spot, so here I am presenting it in more detail:

$$\sum_{i=i_{min}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\beta i \epsilon}}{Z} = \frac{e^{-\beta i _{min}\epsilon} + e^{-\beta (i _{min} + 1)\epsilon} + e^{-\beta (i _{min} + 2)\epsilon}+...}{Z}\\ = \frac{e^{-\beta i _{min}\epsilon} (1+e^{-\beta \epsilon} + e^{-\beta 2\epsilon}+...)}{Z}= e^{-\beta i_{min} \epsilon} \frac{\sum_{i=0} ^ \infty e^{-\beta i\epsilon}}{Z}$$

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! exactly what im looking for. I dont quite understand how you get \begin{equation}\sum_{i=i_{m i n}}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\beta i \epsilon}}{Z}=e^{-\beta i_{\min } \epsilon} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta i \epsilon}}{Z}\end{equation}. Would be really grateful if you can write it for this part step by step how you come to it :)

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope this clarifies it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might momentarily be just an extended comment, too long to type in the appropriate section.
I do not have access to the source you mention, but I am puzzled by the statement you report.
To the best of my understanding $E_a$ in an Arrhenius-type formula represent an energy difference, not an absolute value.
One would expect the decay rate to be proportional to the barrier height between the well and the saddle point, not to the energy of the saddle point itself.
There are of course multiple derivation, at various level of complexity.
A basic one is presented in [Entropy, Order Parameters and Complexity](http://sethna.lassp.cornell.edu/statistical_mechanics_entropy_order_parameters_and_complexity), Exercise 6.11: assuming equilibrium in the well bottom as well as on the saddle, starts by considering the probability ratio between the two location, and this turns out to be $$\exp\frac{-(E_{top}-E_{well})}{kT}$$ where the barrier energy term appears.